# How to set a black background color for text in transparent windows in C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have the following C++ code to open a window and display the frame number.

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

int frameCounter = 0; // Declare frame counter variable as a global variable

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        // Get the client area dimensions
        RECT rect;
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
        int width = rect.right - rect.left;
        int height = rect.bottom - rect.top;

        // Create a compatible DC and bitmap for double buffering
        HDC hdcBuffer = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, width, height);
        HBITMAP hBitmapOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcBuffer, hBitmap);

        // Set text color to green
        SetTextColor(hdcBuffer, RGB(0, 255, 0));// Draw black background rectangle
        HBRUSH hBackgroundBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0));
        FillRect(hdcBuffer, &rect, hBackgroundBrush);
        DeleteObject(hBackgroundBrush);

        // Draw the frame counter text in the buffer
        wchar_t frameText[32];
        swprintf_s(frameText, L"Frame: %d", frameCounter);
        DrawText(hdcBuffer, frameText, -1, &rect, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);

        // Copy the buffer to the window's DC
        BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, width, height, hdcBuffer, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

        // Clean up
        SelectObject(hdcBuffer, hBitmapOld);
        DeleteObject(hBitmap);
        DeleteDC(hdcBuffer);

        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        return 0;
    }

    case WM_ERASEBKGND:
        return 1; // Return 1 to indicate background erased

    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        return 0;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    // Register the window class
    const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[] = L"TransparentWindowClass";

    WNDCLASS wc = {};
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;

    RegisterClass(&wc);

    // Create the window
    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT | WS_EX_TOPMOST,
        CLASS_NAME,
        NULL,
        WS_POPUP,
        0, 0, 200, 200,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL
    );

    // Set the window transparency
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, RGB(0, 0, 0), 0, LWA_COLORKEY);

    if (hwnd == NULL)
        return 0;

    // Show the window
    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    // Message loop
    MSG msg;

    while (true)
    {
        // Process pending messages
        while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
                return msg.wParam;

            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }

        // Update the frame counter
        ++frameCounter;

        // Repaint the window
        RedrawWindow(hwnd, NULL, NULL, RDW_ERASE | RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_FRAME);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You can see I've attempted to make green text that reads the frame number, with a black background directly underneath the text, much like a `color_pair` int the curses library for Python. You can set a background and a foreground for the text. However, despite my efforts, I am only able to make the background white.

This is what I currently have:
[image: current]

This is my goal:
[image: goal]

I've tried everything I can think of, but I only get green text with a white background.
Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Your code is incomplete.

Comment: How so? I can copy the code and compile it by itself.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I couldn't see the scroll bar on the right side.  My mistake.

Comment: SetBkColor(hdcBuffer, RGB(0, 0, 0));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DrawText` uses the device context's background color and mode. You can use `SetBkMode` to set the background mode to either `OPAQUE` or `TRANSPARENT`. If you choose `OPAQUE`, set the background color using `SetBkColor`. This (successfully) shows a black* background for your frame counter. For some reason, the RGB color `0, 0, 0` is transparent(???), so I used `0, 0, 1`:

[image]

```
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        // Get the client area dimensions
        RECT rect;
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
        int width = rect.right - rect.left;
        int height = rect.bottom - rect.top;

        // Create a compatible DC and bitmap for double buffering
        HDC hdcBuffer = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, width, height);
        HBITMAP hBitmapOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcBuffer, hBitmap);

        // Set text color to green
        SetTextColor(hdcBuffer, RGB(0, 255, 0));

        // !!!!!!! Set the background mode of the DC to transparent !!!!!!!!
        SetBkMode(hdcBuffer, OPAQUE);
        SetBkColor(hdcBuffer, RGB(0, 0, 1));

        // Draw the frame counter text in the buffer
        wchar_t frameText[32];
        swprintf_s(frameText, L"Frame: %d", frameCounter);
        DrawText(hdcBuffer, frameText, -1, &rect, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER |
            DT_VCENTER);

        // Copy the buffer to the window's DC
        BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, width, height, hdcBuffer, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

        // Clean up
        SelectObject(hdcBuffer, hBitmapOld);
        DeleteObject(hBitmap);
        DeleteDC(hdcBuffer);

        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        return 0;
    }
```

P.S. there is room for optimization in your code

Comment: Thank you, however this makes the text background transparent when I wanted it to be black.

Comment: I interpreted your title to mean that you wanted the background to be transparent. I'll edit my answer @ArnoldPalmer

Comment: good point. I'll edit my title.

Comment: Alright, there you go! @ArnoldPalmer

Comment: Very nice! Thank you so much.

Comment: I don't understand why 0,0,0 didn't work for you, Windows doesn't treat it specially in any way.